# Remove wordpress post status verification

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I need to show all post to all visitors of the site by direct post URL.
I mean if post is not published and user is not logged in in any case anyone can see the post but not 404 page. Where I must perform changes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a corresponding query before [`The Loop`](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). You can use [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) for this purpose:

**An example:**

```
<?php 

global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 'post_status' => array('publish', 'draft') ) );
query_posts( $args ); 

?>
```

See the Type Parameters documentation [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters).

Hope this helps!

Comment: No...! Don't use `query_posts`. [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/12615)

Comment: Ok, I see, but can you tell me in what WP file I must to do this changes?

Comment: Sorry, but do you understand my situation? I ask how can I show unpublished posts for unregistered users instead of 404 error page. In what WP file and what changes I should perform?